# How to get network usage data in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, networking

In windows taskmanager you could find ethernet usage stats. My question is how do i get these with nodejs.

I've tried using both systemmonitor and os but values i get from them are TX/RX packets and i can't find a way to convert them to KB/s

Comment: I would guess that you need to find some command line networking tool (preferably built into Windows) that you can run using the `child_process` module and gather the output from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into this issue myself and I wasn't able to find an answer, so I coded this myself. This works perfectly fine for me, it just puts the down- and upload rates from the specified network adapter, in my case `Ethernet 2`, in the `networkSpeeds`-object. Note, that this code uses PowerShell, so if you're not using windows or are unable to use PowerShell, this might not work

```js
import * as child_process from "child_process";

let networkSpeeds = {
    download: {
        "bps": null,
        "b/s": null,
        "kbps": null,
        "kb/s": null,
        "mbps": null,
        "mb/s": null,
        "gbps": null,
        "gb/s": null,
    },
    upload: {
        "bps": null,
        "b/s": null,
        "kbps": null,
        "kb/s": null,
        "mbps": null,
        "mb/s": null,
        "gbps": null,
        "gb/s": null,
    },
    lastUpdate: Date.now(),
    lastBytesReceived: 0,
    lastBytesSent: 0,
};

setInterval(() => {
    child_process.exec(`powershell "Get-NetAdapterStatistics -Name 'Ethernet 2'"`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            let response = stdout.trim().replace(/( ){2,}/g, " ");

            let bytesReceived = response.split("\n")[2].split(" ")[response.split("\n")[2].split(" ").length - 4];
            let bytesSent = response.split("\n")[2].split(" ")[response.split("\n")[2].split(" ").length - 2];

            let timePassed = Date.now() - networkSpeeds.lastUpdate;

            // Compare the current BytesReceived and BytesSent to the last time the function was called
            let bytesReceivedSinceLastUpdate = bytesReceived - networkSpeeds.lastBytesReceived;
            let bytesSentSinceLastUpdate = bytesSent - networkSpeeds.lastBytesSent;

            // Check, what the timeDifference is and calculate the speed
            let downloadSpeed = bytesReceivedSinceLastUpdate / (timePassed / 1000);
            let uploadSpeed = bytesSentSinceLastUpdate / (timePassed / 1000);

            networkSpeeds.download["bps"] = downloadSpeed * 8;
            networkSpeeds.download["b/s"] = downloadSpeed;
            networkSpeeds.download["kbps"] = downloadSpeed * 8 / 1000;
            networkSpeeds.download["kb/s"] = downloadSpeed / 1000;
            networkSpeeds.download["mbps"] = downloadSpeed * 8 / 1000000;
            networkSpeeds.download["mb/s"] = downloadSpeed / 1000000;
            networkSpeeds.download["gbps"] = downloadSpeed * 8 / 1000000000;
            networkSpeeds.download["gb/s"] = downloadSpeed / 1000000000;

            networkSpeeds.upload["bps"] = uploadSpeed * 8;
            networkSpeeds.upload["b/s"] = uploadSpeed;
            networkSpeeds.upload["kbps"] = uploadSpeed * 8 / 1000;
            networkSpeeds.upload["kb/s"] = uploadSpeed / 1000;
            networkSpeeds.upload["mbps"] = uploadSpeed * 8 / 1000000;
            networkSpeeds.upload["mb/s"] = uploadSpeed / 1000000;
            networkSpeeds.upload["gbps"] = uploadSpeed * 8 / 1000000000;
            networkSpeeds.upload["gb/s"] = uploadSpeed / 1000000000;

            networkSpeeds.lastBytesReceived = bytesReceived;
            networkSpeeds.lastBytesSent = bytesSent;
            networkSpeeds.lastUpdate = Date.now();
        }
    });
    fs.writeFileSync("temp.json", JSON.stringify(networkSpeeds, null, 6));
}, 1000);
```